# Which web browsers support SVG filtering with a previous layer as the source?

Tags: svg, background, svg-filters

I have created a custom SVG filter which uses the background image as the source. It then applies a random displacement map to it to simulate an optical distortion (e.g. water caustics, warping from hot, flowing air), which I really like.

It renders correctly in Inkscape, but not in Internet Explorer 10 nor Chrome. Apparently, using the background image as a filter input is an obscure feature that some SVG renderers might not support due to the extra memory required to buffer intermediate images. I also had to set enable-background=new in one of the SVG layers for even Inkscape to show it correctly. Does anyone know which web browsers or freely available standalone programs (besides Inkscape) can correctly display such images?

I've attached an example below (you should see a star with the bottom half distorted by the filter).

[Link to live SVG image on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oveqoh/1/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg id="svg1380" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"     style="enable-background:new" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="190" width="367" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<defs id="defs1382">
<filter id="filter1945" style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB">
<feTurbulence id="feTurbulence1947" baseFrequency="0.034000000000000009" seed="397" result="turbulence" numOctaves="4" type="turbulence"/>
<feDisplacementMap id="feDisplacementMap1949" scale="100" yChannelSelector="G" in2="turbulence" xChannelSelector="R" in="BackgroundImage"/>
</filter>
<radialGradient id="radialGradient5645" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cy="402" cx="359" gradientTransform="matrix(.0557 -.0464 .178 .207 268 339)" r="417">
<stop id="stop5641" stop-color="#fee" offset="0"/>
<stop id="stop5643" stop-color="#fee" stop-opacity="0" offset="1"/>
</radialGradient>
<radialGradient id="radialGradient5653" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cy="407" cx="248" gradientTransform="matrix(.537 -.681 .793 .625 -234 -28)" r="47.2">
<stop id="stop5649" stop-color="#f00" offset="0"/>
<stop id="stop5651" stop-color="#784421" offset="1"/>
</radialGradient>
</defs>
<metadata id="metadata1385">
<rdf:RDF>
<cc:Work rdf:about="">
<dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
<dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
<dc:title/>
</cc:Work>
</rdf:RDF>
</metadata>
<g fill-rule="evenodd">
<rect id="rect5726" height="135" width="339" y="0" x="27.9"/>
<path id="path5635" opacity=".998" d="m266 80-36-6-18 31-5-35.4-36-7.5 33-16.1-4-35.9 25 25.8 33-14.8-17 32.1z" fill="url(#radialGradient5653)"/>
<rect id="rect1935" transform="matrix(.435 0 .0110 .656 32.9 -151)" height="189" filter="url(#filter1945)" width="694" y="313" x="-13.6" fill="url(#radialGradient5645)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate. This is actually the 1st version of my question I posted on the graphic design stack exchange since at the time, I didn't think non-programming questions were appropriate on Stack Overflow. Moderators, you should delete this question since my other one is later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background-image is only supported by Opera and IE10 right now as a filter input, so this won't work in most browsers. (and background-image doesn't seem to work in inline SVG in opera - only in .svg files)